# What does William van der Woodsen mean about "Zaire" and the "Democratic Republic of the Congo"?

Tags: plot-explanation, gossip-girl

[*Gossip Girl: The Princess Dowry*](https://gossipgirl.fandom.com/wiki/The_Princess_Dowry) (S05E17) contains the following exchange:

> **William vdW:** *I'm just sorry that Eric couldn't make it back from [Zaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaire).*
>
> **Serena vdW:** *I think they call that the Democratic Republic of Congo now.*
>
> **William vdW:** ***They do, but trust me, it's not.***

William van der Woodsen refers to the *Democratic Republic of the Congo* as [Zaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaire) and is corrected, but replies "*They do, but trust me, it's not.*". Can someone explain to me what this comment means.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Anecdote time. Please feel free to skip to Paragraph 3 :-)

When I studied politics, my tutor would persistently refer to "*Hopfl's rule of Country Naming"*; essentially that whatever a country named itself was actually the diametric opposite of what their system of government really is, citing examples like the 'People's Republic' of China (which is actually authoritarian and communist) or the United Kingdom (which, he argued, is basically a republic and not especially united).

William is (ostentatiously) displaying his superior knowledge of the country. He's suggesting that, in line with Hopfl's Rule, that while the rulers of the country may want people to call it democratic and republican, it's been a corrupt dictatorship for most of its recent history and is presently best described as "[not very democratic](https://freedomhouse.org/country/democratic-republic-congo)".

Comment: My personal favorite: the Democratic People's Republic of Korea, which contains "people" thrice in three different languages (Greek, English, and Latin) and essentially means "the Ruled by the People People's People's Matter of Korea". Or, more recently, the "United" States of America, which couldn't be more divided.

Comment: It should also be noted that Zaire was the name for the country in this region from the '60s until the late 90's. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaire

Comment: Another classic example is the Holy Roman Empire, which is accused of being neither holy, nor Roman, nor an empire.

Comment: @Acccumulation part of which later became the German Democratic Republic. This time at least the German part was true. The latter not so much.

Comment: China calling itself communist is another example of this rule. They are not even remotely communist, in fact they are a totalitarian capitalists with some minor form of central planning, which has nothing at all with communism.

Comment: @Valorum I really like this rule, it is the same vibe as Hanlon's razor, Godwin's law, etc., but I could not find any other reference to it on the Internet - neither "Hopfl's rule" nor "Höpfl's rule", same with "law". It is tongue-in-cheek, so maybe a bit different, but is there anything else apart from a quote from a tutor that mentions that rule?

Comment: @nd. - This was his own rule, and firmly tongue-in-cheek and highly reductive.

Comment: Republic of South Africa is accurate (if you allow for it only being a part of Southern Africa). The United States of America is 2/3rds true, and United Arab Emirates similarly. A Republic is just a place without a monarch, with no requirement for democracy, so e.g. Republic of the Congo is OK although you could dispute the Republic of China. (The United Kingdom is at least a Kingdom these days.)

Comment: @Valorum Was Hopfl the name of your tutor, or some well-known political writer that he was referring to?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Ah, I see the confusion now. This was my tutor and the 'rule' was self-titled

Comment: @StuartF The MacOS dictionary says "a state in which supreme power is held by the people and their elected representatives, and which has an elected or nominated president rather than a monarch." So democracy is part of the definition. Which also means that "democratic republic" is redundant.

Comment: Without further context, I don't see what's "ostentatious" about William's statement.  It just comes off as insulting the country ("But of course it's *really* an oppressive dictatorship"), rather than him claiming to be an expert in African politics.  Maybe his tone doesn't come across well in text.

Comment: FWIW, I've heard that proposed law before, or similar versions, but don't know of any name for it. I will happily call it Hopfl's Law from now on, knowing full well that this is probably in line with [Stigler's Law of Eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy). :P

Comment: @dan04 - In much the same way that you, a regular visitor might correct someone's pronunciation of Gstaad. Or worse, explain that "*tourists call it Gstaad but people who have winter villas there tend to call it 'staad."*

Comment: I think this is the start, but it is not the full story. The Congo was only called Zaire for 26 years, whereas it was the Congo both until William was 9 (so, probably in all of his school textbooks for years after) and for a good decade and a half before the events of the episode. William is probably meant to be shown as a bit out of touch here, maybe even slightly racist—he cannot be bothered to learn what the DRC is currently called, and responds dismissively when corrected.

Comment: @FrancisDavey There's never been a "United Kingdom of Great Britain". It was previously the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland (1801-1922), and the Kingdom of Great Britain (1707-1801) before that.

Comment: It is referred to as the "United Kingdom of Great Britain" in legislation (including the 1706 Act) and official discourse from the union onwards. I am not sure I'd go so far as to say that it never existed.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The joke I always heard was that the Democratic People's Republic of Korea is four lies for the price of one: it's not democratic, it's not for the people, it's not a republic, and it's not (all of) Korea.